# For update simulation in oracle using NHiberante

Tags: nhibernate

Can any one tell me how to implement for update in oracle using NHibernate? Are there any pre defined clauses for this? If not please tell me how can I implement it.

Answer (score 0):

[Read this chapter.](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#transactions-locking)

Basically, you need to get your poco using `ISession.Get(Of Poco)(id, LockMode.Upgrade)`.

As a result, that should issue a `SELECT ... FROM Poco Where Id = ? FOR UPDATE`.

You can also invoke using `LockMode.UpgradeNoWait` to get a equivalent `FOR UPDATE NOWAIT` SQL Statement

Comment: Thanks for your answer Hudler.I have a huge query which is having rownum for getting first result.So i want that result to be locked until i update it.I don't want to share it for another thread.I don't have any Id for comparison .so can i use the above syntax for this scenario?

Comment: The `id` mentioned above is the primary key of the record you want to lock. You gotta have that (NHibernate demands a mapped table always have a PK). You can first query the PK using the *huge statement* you mentioned, and right after that lock the record using what is shown in my answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Hudler.But i think there is some problem with this approach.The method which is giving the result is not Synchronized so there is a chance that multiple threads try to lock the same row.may be that will be a problem in that case right?

Comment: That lock will happen in 2 steps, you are right. But one will always get the lock first. If the second excepts by getting a lock already given, it needs to wait and re-perform the the query + lock request after.